# CloudFront endpoint just change the url to load balancer end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am setting up Amazon CloudFront where the origin is a Load Balancer.

I have able to set CloudFront but their one issue I am facing is that **when I access CloudFront endpoint it just change the url to load balancer end point.**

I have even whitelist (host) in Cache Behavior. When I whitelist only host then end point of CloudFront did not work. Means not able to access the web application which in ELB.

When I whitelist the three header (origin, Referer, & host) then  also not able to access the web application from web browser.

Last I try that I just whitelist (origin, Referer) then able to access the web site. But it just change the url and show the end point if ELB.

Can anyone help me to this?

Comment: Whitelisting HOST header makes the CloudFront to use the same host header which client uses (CNAME or d123xxxx.cloudfront.net) when connecting to load balaner, ELB/ALB also doesn't change the HOST header unless in ALB you have the rule configure, it's the backend which might be redirecting it, check your virtual server config.

Comment: nothing done in virtual server. It is just a simple having  2 EC2 instances in both of them apache was installed using AMI  AWS linux. And add these EC2 to ELB. Now when I configure Cloud Front I have select the ELB End point. And Cloud front was deployed after 15min. I started access the end point of Cloud Front from browser. It just re-direct to ELB endpoint. Showing ELB end point on browser.

Comment: Do u have redirect rule configured on ALB? Also try to invalidate cache of cloudfront and check again, cloudfront also caches 3xx responses.

Comment: I am using classic Load Balancer. Did not how to "3xx responses"

Comment: I am using classic Load Balancer. Did not how to get "3xx responses". Can you give share me little bit approach

Comment: Can any one Please help me in this